# How to control GPIO without sysfs/library

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, gpio, nanopi

I am playing with [NanoPi NEO Core2](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_NEO_Core2) . I installed Ubuntu Core, `sysfs` is working for GPIO control. But, it seems slow to read/write gpio. I checked [WiringNP](https://github.com/friendlyarm/WiringNP), but that seems using `sysfs` system.

Can I control the GPIO pin with C/C++/Assembly language?

Answer (score 2):

Other alternative can be [JoachimSchurig/CppGPIO](https://github.com/JoachimSchurig/CppGPIO).